# WordPress - add_filter function and a string arguement?

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this filter in a piece of code:

```
$output  = apply_filters( 'envira_gallery_output_dynamic_position', $output, $id, $item, $data, $i, 'bottom-right' );
```

My assumption was, that I can make use of it like this:

```
add_filter( 'envira_gallery_output_dynamic_position', 'custom_gallery_output_dynamic_position', 10, 6);

function custom_gallery_output_dynamic_position($output, $id, $item, $data, $i, 'bottom-right' ) {
```

But because of the 'bottom-right' I get a 500 server error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''bottom-right'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

Does anybody know how I can use this filter correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be variable name:

```
function custom_gallery_output_dynamic_position($output, $id, $item, $data, $i, $position) {
```

You can define it with default value:

```
function custom_gallery_output_dynamic_position($output, $id, $item, $data, $i, $position='bottom-right') {
```

Comment: I got it now. Thanks